# Drop row from data-frame where that contains a specific string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a number of CSV files where the head looks something like:

```
09/07/2014,26268315,,
10/07/2014,6601181,16.3857
11/07/2014,916651,12.5879
14/07/2014,213357,,
15/07/2014,205019,10.8607
```

I need to read this into a dataframe and remove any rows with `,,` however when I read the CSV data into a dataframe using:

```
df = pd.read_csv(raw_directory+'\\'+filename, error_bad_lines=False,header=None)
```

I get:

```
            0         1        2   3
0  09/07/2014  26268315      NaN NaN
1  10/07/2014   6601181  16.3857 NaN
2  11/07/2014    916651  12.5879 NaN
3  14/07/2014    213357      NaN NaN
4  15/07/2014    205019  10.8607 NaN
```

How can I read the CSV data into a dataframe and get:

```
                             0 
 0       09/07/2014,26268315,,
 1  10/07/2014,6601181,16.3857
 2   11/07/2014,916651,12.5879
 3         14/07/2014,213357,,
 4   15/07/2014,205019,10.8607
```

I need to remove any rows where there are `,,` present. and then resave the adjusted dataframe to a new CSV file.  I was going to use:

```
stringList = [',,']

df = df[~df[0].isin([stringList])]
```

to remove the rows with ,, present so the resulting .csv head looks like:

```
10/07/2014,6601181,16.3857
11/07/2014,916651,12.5879
15/07/2014,205019,10.8607
```

Comment: To be honest, It seems like you don't need pandas for that. Just read the file, and `strip(',,')` each line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess here is possible remove all columns with all `NaN`s and then rows with any `NaN`s:

```
df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all').dropna()
print (df)
            0        1        2
1  10/07/2014  6601181  16.3857
2  11/07/2014   916651  12.5879
4  15/07/2014   205019  10.8607
```

Another solution is add separator which value is not in data like `|` and then filter by [`endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(raw_directory+'\\'+filename, error_bad_lines=False,header=None, sep='|')
df = df[~df[0].str.endswith(',')]
#alternative solution - $ is for end of string
#df = df[~df[0].str.contains(',$')]
print (df)
                            0
1  10/07/2014,6601181,16.3857
2   11/07/2014,916651,12.5879
4   15/07/2014,205019,10.8607
```